# How to remove "Using Log instead of Timber" warning in Android Studio?

Tags: android, android-studio

I added a couple dependencies to my Android project (both mapbox-related, I believe), and now I'm getting the following warning in my code:

[image]

[image]

How can I remove all warnings of this? I'm aware I can add @SuppressLint to remove warnings for this function but I want to remove all of these warnings from my app.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

Go to Android Studio Preferences.

[image]

Go to Editor -> Inspections -> Lint

[image]

Then search for Timber and uncheck "Logging call to Log instead of Timber"
[image]

Be aware that this will turn off this lint check for all of your projects

Comment: Is there a way to configure this in gradle?

Comment: this is worst solution if you are using CI/CD :D

Comment: @ShivamPokhriyal All lint.xml file to the project root folder. File should contain 
    <issue id="LogNotTimber" severity="ignore" />. Link to the documentation: https://developer.android.com/studio/write/lint#sample-lint.xml-file

Answer (score 6):

Even though the accepted answer works. If you want a more robust solution instead of disabling it manually, you can add these to your `lintOptions` in `build.gradle:app`

```
android {
//...


lintOptions {
        disable 'TimberArgCount', 'TimberArgTypes', 'TimberTagLength', 'BinaryOperationInTimber',
                'LogNotTimber', 'StringFormatInTimber', 'ThrowableNotAtBeginning'
    }


//...
}
```

This works better instead of disabling it in ide settings

Comment: Thanks. This is the best solution for disabling it just on a single project, avoiding missing the linting on other projects using timber.

Answer (score 1):

add `exclude group: "com.jakewharton.timber", module: 'timber'` to the dependency that uses Timber

For example:

```
implementation("com.raygun:raygun4android:4.0.1") {
  exclude group: "com.jakewharton.timber", module: 'timber'
}
```